strsplit not splitting correctly on the space when second word is short
I want to get a list of species from Wikidata and then extract the specific name (the second word) of the species name. To make sure I don't get wrong results, I want to filter only names with two words, as all species should have only two words. I used strsplit splitting at the spaces (" ") to check the number of words. However, some species with two words are getting counted as having one word. I've tried alternatives to the " " space (like described here and here) but they didn't work.
I used WikidataQueryServiceR package to get the species names from Wikidata. The query is working fine.
Here's a reproducible example with a specific genus:
# How many words in Leptobrachella eos?

# Install packages
install.packages("WikidataQueryServiceR")
library(WikidataQueryServiceR)

# Run query
# This query will return every species in the Leptobrachella genus
df<-query_wikidata('SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?taxon_name WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
  {
    SELECT DISTINCT ?item WHERE {
      ?item p:P171 ?statement0.
      ?statement0 ps:P171 wd:Q2142033.
    }
    LIMIT 100
  }
  OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P225 ?taxon_name. }
}') # fim do query

# See results and turn df into a data.frame
df
df %>% data.class # originally "spec_tbl_df"
df <- as.data.frame(df)
df[80,2] # returns "Leptobrachella eos", an example of the problem
df[80,2] %>% data.class # now "character"

# Try to split the taxon_name in the spaces
strsplit(df[80,2]," ")
strsplit(df[80,2],"\\s+")
strsplit(df[80,2],"[[:space:]]")
strsplit(df[80,2],"[[:blank:]]")
# none of these work

# Species with different than 2 words get to the non_binomial dataframe
non_binomial <- df %>%  filter(sapply(strsplit(taxon_name, " "), length) != 2) # check species with other than 2 words


When I check the non_binomial dataframe, I get species Leptobrachella feii, nyx, yeae and eos, all with four or fewer letters in the second word. Could this short word be related to the problem? Is there a better way to split and count words in a character?
I expected to see only species with one or three or more words in the non_binomial dataframe.

Consider including the head of df$taxon_name. And mostly those that also dont work as youd expect. perhaps you should use str_count instead. and check for those that do not have 2 words

A likely cause is that the problematic cases use a non-ascii space character, e.g. a non-breaking space.

str_count appears to have worked!
